# Brace expansion to run program multiple times with different arguments

Tags: command-line, brace-expansion

I just learned about brace expansion and hoped I could make use of them to launch the same C++ program with different command line arguments.

My code is run like this from the terminal:

```
mpirun -n 1 main.exe 1 10 0.1 1 5
```

The numbers after main.exe are the input arguments of my program.

I would like to do something like this:

```
mpirun -n 1 main.exe 1 10 {0.1,0.2} 1 5
```

where I expect the code to be run twice, once with 0.1 and once with 0.2 as the third argument.

Why does it not work and how can I fix it?

Best

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that won't work. Brace expansions are expanded when you run the command. Only the brace expansion is affected, they don't cause you to run multiple commands. In your case, this:

```
mpirun -n 1 main.exe 1 10 {0.1,0.2} 1 5
```

Will simply become this:

```
mpirun -n 1 main.exe 1 10 0.1 0.2 1 5
```

If you want to run it twice, with different values, you could do something like this instead:

```
for i in {0.1,0.2}; do
    mpirun -n 1 main.exe 1 10 "$i" 1 5
done
```

And that will run

```
mpirun -n 1 main.exe 1 10 0.1 1 5
```

followed by

```
mpirun -n 1 main.exe 1 10 0.2 1 5
```

Of course, in this specific case, the brace expansion is needlessly complicated and you should just do:

```
for i in 0.1 0.2; do
    mpirun -n 1 main.exe 1 10 "$i" 1 5
done
```

---

A useful trick for understanding this sort of thing is `set -x` (assuming you're using bash) which will show you what command is actually being executed:

```
$ set -x
$ mpirun -n 1 main.exe 1 10 {0.1,0.2} 1 5
+ mpirun -n 1 main.exe 1 10 0.1 0.2 1 5
[. . .]
```

You can turn it off again with `set +x`, but using this lets you see exactly how a complex command is expanded by the shell and check what is really being executed.

Comment: in other words, the key is that brace expansion produces multiple words/fields/command line arguments, not multiple _commands_. (I'm mostly saying this because that was the point of the first sentence of the answer I was too slow to write.)

Answer (score 3):

This question does come up every now and then and the general consensus is that a `for` loop is the best/safest way to achieve what you're trying to do.

That being said, you could use brace expansion with a construct like this (e.g. four different arguments)

```
printf 'mpirun -n 1 main.exe 1 10 %s 1 5\n' {p1,p2,p3,p4} | sh
```

i.e. you build up multiple command lines via `printf` that are piped to and executed by `sh`<sup>1</sup>.
Another way: if you have `gnu parallel` installed you can run

```
parallel mpirun -n 1 main.exe 1 10 {} 1 5 ::: {p1,p2,p3,p4}
```

In both cases, `{p1,p2,p3,p4}` is expanded by the shell to `p1 p2 p3 p4` which are then used, one at a time, by `printf`'s `%s` and respectively `parallel`'s `{}` (you can view those as placeholders...)

---

If you're trying to save typing in interactive mode then you should consult the history expansion chapter from your shell manual, e.g. with `zsh` (and `setopt histexpand`) you could run the command

```
mpirun -n 1 main.exe 1 10 0.1 1 5
```

then use history expansion to run the same command but with `0.2` as the 6th argument (count starts at 0)

```
!:-5 0.2 !:7*
```

and so on for other values, e.g. `XYZ`

```
!:-5 XYZ !:7*
```

---

<sup>1: this assumes you know what you are doing... you don't want to pipe stuff like `rm -rf *` to `sh`</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```
mpirun -n 1 main.exe 1 10 {0.1,0.2} 1 5
```

expand to

```
mpirun -n 1 main.exe 1 10 0.1 0.2 1 5
```

which might no be what you want.

note that `{a,b,c}` expand to `a b c`

you might want to run

```
for x in 0.1 0.2
do
    mpirun -n 1 main.exe 1 10 "$x" 1 5
done
```

which can be one lined, but hardly save keystroke on interactive run.

Comment: That makes so much sense! Thank you, it worked!